# Are my IF statements incorrect?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have the following:

```
var detail = 'two';

function chkDetail(detail){
    if(detail == 'one') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('one');
    }
    if(detail == 'two') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('two');
    }
    if(detail == 'three') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('three');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('NO');
    } 
}
```

Depending on what string is passed into my function, I want the appropriate message to be passed into my `valMsg` div.

In the above scenario, my function keeps returning `NO`.

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Are the `if` statements incorrect?

Comment: Make the first one an if, and the the middle ones else ifs. Or use a switch.

Comment: The `else` is only for the *last* `if`.

Comment: Would not the Switch statement be a better option than IF in this example?

Comment: It is frustrating when someone votes to close a question without an explanation or constructive criticism.

Comment: Go through your own logic using "one" as an example. See the first two comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've separated the conditions.  I'll add spacing to illustrate:

```
// first condition
if(detail == 'one') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('one');
}

// second condition
if(detail == 'two') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('two');
}

// third condition
if(detail == 'three') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('three');
}
else {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('NO');
}
```

So if, for example, `detail` is "one" then:

- First condition enters the `if` block
- Second condition does not enter the `if` block
- Third condition does not enter the `if` block, ***does*** enter the `else` block (since `else` is the logical inverse of `if`)

If they should all be the same condition, use `else if` blocks:

```
// all one condition
if(detail == 'one') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('one');
}
else if(detail == 'two') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('two');
}
else if(detail == 'three') {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('three');
}
else {
    jQuery('#valMsg').text('NO');
}
```

This way as soon as one block is entered, the rest are skipped because the condition as a whole has been satisfied.

Answer (score 5):

Should add `else` on all statements:

```
function chkDetail(detail){
    if(detail == 'one') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('one');
    }
    else if(detail == 'two') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('two');
    }
    else if(detail == 'three') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('three');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('NO');
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `else` is referring to the previous `if` only, not to all of the `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

The answers supplied here do not check on the datatype, what could be crucial for the check.

```
var int1 = 1
var string1 = '1'
```

`if(string1 == int1)` would return true but they are actually not the same.

I would use the switch statement that is better looking code and does also check on datatype.

```
var detail = 'two';

function chkDetail(detail){
switch(detail){
case 'one' : jQuery('#valMsg').text('one'),
case 'two' : jQuery('#valMsg').text('two'),
default :  jQuery('#valMsg').text('No')
}
```

If you want to go the route of the multiple if statements, then please use the `===` operator to make sure there is a check on datatype as well. This will prevent a lot of sketchy behaviour and bugs.

```
    if(detail === 'one') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('one');
    }
    if(detail === 'two') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('two');
    }
    if(detail === 'three') {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('three');
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#valMsg').text('NO');
    } 
}
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) and [this](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/07/javascript-switch-statement-quirks/) for more information.